# React state change or page refresh on loading new page

Tags: reactjs, redux, routes

I have a react app with hamburger menu which slides in/out above the page content.  I connected redux to handle the sidemenu state, which toggles classes for body and overlay to prevent scroll.

When the sidemenu is active, and I click on one of the navlinks within it, the page does load the new page, but the sidemenu is still open.

I'm currently using `BrowserRouter` with `Switch` and `Route` in `App.js`

How do I change the state when it navigates to a new page?

Some of the things I considered are:

- Adding onClick handler to each of the sidemenu links (`Link` components for now).
- Add `componentDidMount` on each of the pages

Is there a better way?  I don't want to add onClick event to all the items in the sidemenu as it grows later, nor do I want to add componentDidMount to each of the pages as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect router to your menu component and detect location changes:

```
class Menu extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.location.pathname !== prevProps.location.pathname) {
      /** change redux state here */
    }
  }

  ....
}

export default withRouter(Menu);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response, it worked nicely.